# Printing in android studio - folding sections

Tags: java, android, eclipse, printing, android-studio

When I was printing java code in Eclipse, the way of printing was WYSIWYG. So if I folded some selected sections (for example import section, but also any other foldable section), it was printed as folded.
In Android Studio code is printed allways fully unfolded. Does anybody know some way (plugin or some preferences setting etc.), how to set it to print also in the folding WYSIWYG style?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I have done the printing part in android device when the printer is already configured on the device.
If the printer is not configured on the device, the exception occurs can you tell that how u know that printer is configured on device

```
e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String name=e1.getText().toString();
        PrintManager printManager=(PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        //PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = view.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi nikhil"+name+""+printManager.getPrintJobs(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          String text=this.getString(R.string.app_name)+"Document";
//        printManager.getPrintJobs();

         printManager.print(text, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this), null);
        Log.d("print", "print" + printManager);
```

Comment: i have the same problem if any solution plz mail at nikhilgardi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

on Android-Studio 4.0, I noticed that you can select the parts of a file you wish to print, and in the print dialog box, it will allow you to just print the selection. This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it is a way to bypass the long lines of import statements and comments at the head of a file.